# à l'époque contemporaine, les gens prononcent-ils le "e" à la fin de "jaune"?

Tags: prononciation

la langue française a beaucoup changé au fil des années.

après l'an 2000, est-il devenu courant pour les personnes nées en france de prononcer la lettre « e » à la fin du mot « jaune » ?

Comment: Je ne ressens pas ce changement particulièrement depuis l'an 2000. Je ne crois pas que cela ait changé de façon significative depuis la deuxième guerre mondiale au moins.

Answer (score 3):

Toutes les langues **vivantes** changent au fil des années.

La caducité des *E* finals n'est pas (ou plus) une question d'époque mais de lieu. Ces *E* sont muets depuis bien plus longtemps que l'an 2000 (l'amenuisement des *E* non toniques a été progressif sur une période de plusieurs siècles) à l'exception notable des aires où un substrat occitan, catalan ou corse conduit les personnes ayant « l'accent » à le prononcer.

Les *E* non muets peuvent aussi se renconter en poésie.

> *On voit sur votre teint une jaune pâleur*
> Robert Cambert, *Pomone*, 1671

Answer (score 0):

Bien avant l'an 2000, c'est à dire déjà en 1950, le e ne se prononce pas, assez généralement ; dans certaines régions, en particulier chez les moins éduqués, le e peut être prononcé, et cela d'une manière plus ou moins marquée ; il peut être assez fortement prononcé dans la région de Marseille. Par exemple, à Toulouse, alors qu'on trouve partout « qu'est's qu'c'est" pour « qu'est ce que c'est », on pourra entendre « qu'est c**e** qu**e** c'est ».

Voici une [vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpoaodwmkJc) dans laquelle on peut clairement entendre le e final dans le parler de la journaliste toulousaine (déboir**e**, judiciair**e**, Républiqu**e**), *et* dans celui de Mélanchon, mais attention, ne pas faire comme lui, parce qu'en marquant très distinctement le parler toulousain, alors que n'étant pas toulousain il ne parle pas de cette façon d'habitude, il laisse à croire qu'il pourrait se  moquer de la journaliste.

Néanmoins le e n'était certainement plus prononcé déjà bien avant 1950. C'est une question qui concerne bien plus que le e final dans les mots tels que « jaune », « rouge », « orage », « page », etc. Les son de « eu »  et de « e » à l'intérieur des mots peuvent être muets, et cela varie selon les régions parfois. Il y a quelques indications sur [ce site](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/02/25/6999/). Mais c'est peu et même un français ne sait pas tout ça ; il peut bien connaitre les habitudes dans sa région et guère plus ; par exemple il existe en plus des deux prononciations qui sont données pour « cheveux » (cheuveux, ch'feux), la prononciation « ch'veux ».

Comment: La raison du vote négatif ? Qu'est-ce qu'il y a de faux ? On peut savoir ? À la tête du client, comme d'habitude ?

Comment: Les "moins éduqués" sans doute.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, mais prononcer les e  n'est pas véritablement un critère d'instruction ; j'ai encore remarqué ça hier en écoutant Élizabeth Borne : elle prononce les e finaux.

Comment: Donc Éli**s**abeth Borne est instruite, mais "mal éduquée" ?

Comment: @jlliagre Donc et malheureusement le mot « éduqué » veut dire « instruit », et il aurait fallu s'en soucier plus tôt : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20moins%20%C3%A9duqu%C3%A9s%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: Selon toi, l'instruction (ou l'éducation puisque ce serait la même chose d'après une recherche Google) consiste donc à enseigner l'accent pointu aux francophones qui n'ont pas eu la chance de naître là où il va de soi ?

Comment: @jlliagre Ça n'est évidemment pas ce que j'écris. Je dit seulement qu'il y a des gens instruits qui prononcent les e, bien que ce ne soit pas le cas général.

Comment: Tu écris que les gens instruits, en général, ne prononcent pas les *E* muets finals. Il y a donc un rapport entre accent et instruction, c'est ça ?

Comment: @jlliagre Je suspecte qu'il y en a un, mais si c'est le cas je n'ai pas de certitude sur ce que ce rapport pourrait être.  Il est possible qu'il ne s'agisse que d'un aspect pratique :  par exemple, plus on est instruit plus on se sert de la langue, plus on aurait tendance à parler vite, plus cela induirait à se passer de sons qui ne sont pas absolument nécessaires.

Comment: [Qu'est-ceuh queu ça veux direuh...](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/life/article/melenchon-se-moque-de-l-accent-du-sud-mais-c-est-loin-d-etre-l-accent-le-plus-discrimine_133188.html)